# How to use variables in Discord Bot Embed Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, discord, embedding

I'm trying to make my code more efficient for my discord bot by using the from_dict method for my help command embedded messages, but it's not wanting to let me use the message variable because it hasn't been declared yet in the dictionary, even though the command function takes in the variable that would be used for the dictionary that holds it.

Here's my code to hopefully try to explain it better than I tried,

```
    message = discord.Message
helpDict = {'footer': {'text': f'Requested by: {message.author.display_name}', 'icon_url': f'{message.author.avatar_url}'}, 
'author': {'name': 'Anuva Seshat, the Book Keeper', 'icon_url': 'https://i.postimg.cc/FRfS9pw4/Magi-Matured.jpg'}, 
'fields': [], 
'color': 15844367, 'type': 'rich', 'description': '', 'title': ''
}

# Custom Help Commands
@bot.group(invoke_without_command = True)
async def help(message):
  tempDict = helpDict
  tempDict['title'] = f'Help, provided by {bot.user}'
  tempDict['description'] = '$help lists all commands in their respective categories.'
  # tempDict['footer']['text'] = f'Requested by: {message.author.display_name}'
  # tempDict['footer']['icon_url'] = f'{message.author.avatar_url}'
  tempDict['fields'].append({'inline': False, 'name': 'DM Commands', 'value': 'Commands for the DM role only: $addLesson, $addPainting, $answers, $grade, $newNPC, $play, $readmit, $removeLesson'})
  tempDict['fields'].append({'inline': False, 'name': 'DM & Student Commands', 'value': 'Commands for both Student and DM roles: $grades, $showNPC'})
  tempDict['fields'].append({'inline': False, 'name': 'Fun Commands', 'value': 'Commands of fun for all: $guessingGame, $hello, $painting, $roll'})
  tempDict['fields'].append({'inline': False, 'name': 'Student Commands', 'value': 'Commands for the Student role only: $enlist, $lesson, $quiz'})
  tempDict['fields'].append({'inline': False, 'name': 'Testing Commands', 'value': 'Commands for the DM role to test the bot: $initDB, $init_testNPC, $showDB, $showNpcList, $showTestNPC, $testEmbed, $testPicDB'})
  tempDict['fields'].append({'inline': False, 'name': 'Message Deletion', 'value': 'For help message deletion, please react to the message.'})
  em = discord.Embed.from_dict(tempDict)

  await message.send(embed = em)
  await message.message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the helpDict array you are using the message variable which SENDS the message not gets it.

You need to use the "{message.author.display_name}" inside of the command because that's the only place it gets the message author from.

The message variable your needing to get is the "async def help(***message***)" one.

.

.

NOT THIS IGNORE EDITED:
Could it be because your dict is called "helpDict" and the 'em' variable is trying to get "tempDict"?

Comment: No, cause I assigned helpDict to tempDict, which means tempDict would be the exact same thing. I'm having problems with having tempDict take in the message argument in the function without having to do it myself every time I want to use the help dictionary.

Comment: Edited please refer.

Comment: Sigh, alright. I wasn't sure if there was a way to kinda "automate" the message variable. So that I could edit that part of the embed from one place instead of having to edit multiple places whenever I would change it to something else. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear but I'll try to cover a few things that you might have missed.

When you do `tempDict = helpDict` you are creating a reference. Feel free to view a guide on [using copy](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/shallow-deep-copy)

```py
import copy

def just_assignment(d1):
  print("just_assignment")
  d2 = d1
  d2['edited'] = "new"
  print(d1 == d2)

def using_copy(d1):
  print("using copy.copy")
  d2 = copy.copy(d1)
  d2['edited'] = "new"
  print(d1 == d2)

def using_deep_copy(d1):
  print("using copy.deepcopy")
  d2 = copy.deepcopy(d1)
  d2['edited'] = "new"
  print(d1 == d2)
  
just_assignment({"foo" : "bar"})
# just_assignment
# True

using_copy({"foo" : "bar"})
# using copy.copy
# False

using_deep_copy({"foo" : "bar"})
# using copy.deepcopy
# False
```

Given you are creating a placeholder embed via `helpDict`, why not just add the fields when they are present?

```py
helpDict = { 
'author': {'name': 'Anuva Seshat, the Book Keeper', 'icon_url': 'https://i.postimg.cc/FRfS9pw4/Magi-Matured.jpg'}, 
'fields': [], 
'color': 15844367, 'type': 'rich', 'description': '', 'title': ''
}

# Custom Help Commands
@bot.group(invoke_without_command = True)
async def help(message):
  tempDict = copy.copy(helpDict)
  tempDict.update({
    'footer': {
      'text': f'Requested by: {message.author.display_name}', 
      'icon_url': f'{message.author.avatar_url}',
    }
  })
```

Hopefully, this helps!

-----------------X------------------X------------------------

A little more information on how you can go about re-using embeds and writing minimal code. Consider [looking here for all methods](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#embed)

```py
def get_default_embed(title : str, description : str):
  embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description= description, color=15844367)
  embed.set_author(name="Anuva Seshat, the Book Keeper", icon_url="https://i.postimg.cc/FRfS9pw4/Magi-Matured.jpg")
  # Adding a few more things for you to consider
  embed.set_thumbnail(url=guild.icon_url_as(format="png"))
  return embed

  
@bot.group(invoke_without_command = True)
async def help(message):
  _commands = [
      {
          "name": "DM Commands",
          "value": "Commands for the DM role only: $addLesson, $addPainting, $answers, $grade, $newNPC, $play, $readmit, $removeLesson",
      },
      {
          "name": "DM & Student Commands",
          "value": "Commands for both Student and DM roles: $grades, $showNPC",
      },
      {
          "name": "Fun Commands",
          "value": "Commands of fun for all: $guessingGame, $hello, $painting, $roll",
      },
      {
          "name": "Student Commands",
          "value": "Commands for the Student role only: $enlist, $lesson, $quiz",
      },
      {
          "name": "Testing Commands",
          "value": "Commands for the DM role to test the bot: $initDB, $init_testNPC, $showDB, $showNpcList, $showTestNPC, $testEmbed, $testPicDB",
      },
      {
          "name": "Message Deletion",
          "value": "For help message deletion, please react to the message.",
      },
  ]
  embed = get_default_embed(title=f'Help, provided by {bot.user}', description='$help lists all commands in their respective categories.')
  for command in _commands:
    embed.add_field(name=command['name'], value=command['value'], inline=False)

  embed.set_footer(text=f'Requested by: {message.author.display_name}', icon_url=f'{message.author.avatar_url}')
  await message.send(embed = embed)
  await message.message.delete()
```

Comment: This certainly gives me a new view on things. Thanks for the answer! I was mostly just wanting to make it to where I could edit part of the embeds from one place instead of having to change said part for multiple embeds (cause I have at least a dozen help command functions which use almost the same exact embed structure save for a few differences). But if it's not possible to do something like that with the message variable, then I'll just have to stick with what I got for the most part. Again, thanks for answering!

Comment: Glad it could help! @TheDraconic I have updated the answer with another way that I use. You can also think of creating a custom Embed class which will give you more control over how you set things!

Comment: This is also helpful. I'll take your idea into consideration.